# How to write a function generating Fibonacci series smaller than a given number (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

Here's my code:

```js
function fibs(num) {
  //generate Fibonacci numbers:
  let arr = [1,1]
  let i = 2;
  function fibsRange(i) {
    arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2]
    if (arr[i] < num) {
      fibsRange(i+1);//call function one more time;
    }
      return arr
  }
  return fibsRange();      
}
console.log(fibs(5));
```

Assume that given number (num) is bigger than 2. Where do I get wrong?

Note: I edited my code.

Comment: Presumably you'd want `return <something>` in your `fibs()` function, otherwise it doesn't return anything

Comment: Where do you call `fibsRange`?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, first time using stackoverflow. I edited my code above.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Edit your question and add or modify the code there.

Comment: @jabaa. I edited my code above, thanks.

Comment: `fibsRange` expects 1 parameter but you are passing none. There's also a _"Tidy"_ button in the StackSnippet editor; I suggest you use it

Comment: With ES2022, something like this should do: `const fib = (lim, ar = [0, 1]) => ar.at(-1) + ar.at(-2) < lim ? fib(lim, ar.concat([ar.at(-1) + ar.at(-2)])) : (ar); console.log(fib(5));`

Comment: I'm a newbie to code and to this site. And  I already learns so many things in 2 hours using stackoverflow. You guys are great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is checking if `arr[i] < num`, then invoke the `fibsRange(i+1)`. This is a wrong logic, you will always get the fibbonacci number just higher than the `num` because you are already setting it at `arr[i]` and then checking the condition. However, you should first check if `arr[i] < num`, and then push it into `arr`.

```
function fibs(num) {
  //generate Fibonacci numbers:
  let arr = [1, 1];
  let i = 2;
  function fibsRange(i) {
    const lastFibNumber = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
    if (lastFibNumber < num) {
      arr.push(lastFibNumber);
      fibsRange(i + 1); //call function one more time;
    }
    return arr;
  }
  return fibsRange(i);
}

console.log(fibs(5));
```

Comment: I did. I already learns so many things in 2 hours using stackoverflow. You guys are great. It's my first time.

Comment: `fibs(5)` returns `[1,1,2,3]`. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes @CarstenMassmann. If he calls `fibs(10)`, he will get the fibbonacci number where last number is less than `10`

Answer (score 1):

first :as mentionned by Phil your function (the first one) needs to return something.
second: you don't need 2 functions, one will do the job.
here's a working version of your code (I also modified some unnecessary code.

Edit: I added the case when you need to parse just one parameter

```js
function fibsRange(i,arr,num) {
  if(arr[i-1]+arr[i-2] > num) return arr
  else{
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2]
    return fibsRange(i + 1,arr,num);
  }
}
//in case you need just one parameter
function fib(num){
  let arr = [1, 1];
  let i = 2;
  return fibsRange(i,arr,num);
}

//those(declaration of arr and i) are unnecessary in case you use fib
let arr = [1, 1]
let i = 2;
console.log(fibsRange(i,arr,5));
console.log(fib(5));
```

Comment: I'd suggest that the initialisation of the array shouldn't be the responsibility of calling code

Comment: Thank you. But I would like the function fibsRange to accept only one parameter.

Comment: yeah @Phil i agree with you, but I considered the case when he needs the array later in the code.

Comment: Thank you @ZakiRyad, I do need the array later in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You never called your `fibsRange()` function and never returned anything from `fibs()`.

The following version works.

```js
function fibs(num) {
  //generate Fibonacci numbers:
  let arr = [1, 1]
  if (num>1) fibsRange(2); 

  function fibsRange(i) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2]
    if (arr[i] < num) {
      fibsRange(i + 1); //call function one more time;
    }       
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(fibs(5)); //undified;
```

Comment: Well, this checks, whether `num>1` and we actually need to call `fibsRange()` or whether we simply return the initial array `[1,1]`.

Comment: Thank you it works. It looks just like my code. What kind of magic is this?

Comment: What is the logic behind   `if (num>1) fibsRange(2); ` ?

Comment: See my first comment: for `num<=1` I simply return the initial `arr=[1,1]`. Otherwise I start the recursion process with `fibsRange(2)`. This function will repeatedly call itself while  `arr[i]<num`.

Comment: It's still confusing to me. so the number `2` in `fibsRange(2)` refers to `i = 2`, right? Why don't you simply call `fibsRange()`, without number `2`?

Comment: `i` only exists within the local function `fibsRange(i){...}`.It needs to be set initially by calling `fibsRange(2)`, otherwise you will start with an undefined value. I moved the `return arr` from `fibsRange()` to the outer function since `fibsRange(i)` always works on the "in scope" array `arr`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function fibs(num) {
    //generate Fibonacci numbers:
    let arr = [1, 1];
    while(arr[arr.length-1] <= num){
        let y = arr[arr.length-1] + arr[arr.length-2];
        if(y > num){
            break; // break if new y is greater than num
        }
        arr.push(y); // add y to the serie
    }
    return arr; //// return the serie
}
console.log(fibs(50));
```

Comment: Could you add a description, explaining the problems in the code and the differences in your code?

Comment: Thank you, this should get rid of the need to use `i`.